# Mail on my IPhone 5s won't be delivered when app is not open

Tags: mail.app, iphone

I have an iPhone 5s. I can't receive any e-mail when the app Mail is not open. 
Instead, when the app is open I receive all the e-mail that someone send to me and appears instantly. What should I do to receive a warning when I receive a new e-mail?

Comment: It depends on your email provider, they need to have push capabilities. (Gmail used to, but Google removed the functionality.)